# Numeric cell with 0 not null

Tags: select, oracle-sql-developer

I have the following query (in a Oracle Database):

```
          SELECT SUM (CANTITATE)
             FROM ANEXA2A_TABEL2_ROWS
            WHERE TIP_ACTIUNE = 'COLECTATE'
                  AND TIP_AMB = 'STICLA'
                  AND COD LIKE '%*'
```

The problem is that if I don't have any row with * in COD, the result is a empty cell and I want it 0. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`NVL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm).

```
 SELECT NVL(SUM(CANTITATE),0)
             FROM ANEXA2A_TABEL2_ROWS
            WHERE TIP_ACTIUNE = 'COLECTATE'
                  AND TIP_AMB = 'STICLA'
                  AND COD LIKE '%*';
```

That'll make the `SUM()` function return `0` if it would ordinarily return `NULL`.